# How to solve for a Phase Function Cumulative Distribution function (CDF) calculation give a pdf ...

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am attempting to solve for the CDF (more specifically the inverse CDF, but that is easy once I have the CDF) - Cumulative Distribution function given a Probability Distribution Function (pdf) and g parameter.

Which from what I understand you need to solve for the integral of the PDF

Specifically for [Corntte-Shanks](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-31-16-3152):
$$F(\theta) = 1/(4\pi) * 3(1-g^2) / (2(2+g^2)) * (1+\cos^2(\theta)) / (1 + g^2 - 2g*\cos(\theta))^{3/2} $$

Where:
$\mu = <cosTheta>= 3g(g^2 + 4)/(5(2+g^2))$ (which you flip to solve for g, which is in the paper, but messy to type)

Now for HG this is [straightforward](http://www.astro.umd.edu/~jph/HG_note.pdf) where here (1) is the PDF and (7) is the CDF for Henyey-Greenstein phase function.

Essentially I am trying to find a way to solve for the CDF.

(As a side note, I am ok if there is a simple way to solve it by discretizing and somehow hand solving the integral and creating a tabulated CDF, since I feel like the integral of the PDF of the CS phase function is just messy, Maple threw up trying to solve it)

Comment: I am adding this as a comment as technically this should be explained here on Stackoverflow but there's a complete explanation of this precise question here on Scatchapixel: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/monte-carlo-methods-in-practice/monte-carlo-simulation